# Error with drop down menu (select tag) with Material and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select

I have this:

```
<select ng-model="vm.areaSeleccionada" ng-options="area.CODAREA as area.NOMAREA for area in vm.areas">
</select>
```

And my controller has:

```
vm.areas = [
{CODAREA:1,
NOMAREA:"ALGO"}
]
```

It doesn't work. If I use ng-repeat with the select tag, It doesn't work.
But If I use a table with ng-repeat it works.

It doesn't load anything. It shows: undefined, in select tag.

UPDATE:
If I prove the same code in another HTML, it works. But If I use the script for material select, it generates two selects:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').material_select();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the class "browser-default" in the select tag.
I guess that MaterializeCSS changes the normal behavior of drop down menu.

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-model="vm.areaSeleccionada" ng-options="area.CODAREA as area.NOMAREA for area in vm.areas">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Human you need to initialize        vm like that then you have it in list.Look at the the plunkr created for you http://plnkr.co/edit/O95NgX7GZUbDetdzRmyD

```
    $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.vm={};
  $scope.vm.areas = [
{CODAREA:1,
NOMAREA:"ALGO"}
]
});
```

Comment: I use controllers so:
ng-controller="preguntasController as vm". vm is the equivalent to $scope.